# Android Viewpager with asynctasks (spinner while page is loading)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oncreate, android-viewpager

I want a Viewpager that shows loading while content is coming in from the background. Basically I expect the first View to be loaded, but View+1 and View-1 will still be loading. If the user swipes to either side I want them to be presented with a spinning dialog while it loads

Would I just add AsyncTasks into the ViewPager with some conditions determining when they will run? I dont want too many AsyncTasks to be loading as the viewpager will have many views off to the sides.

I think the Trulia app does this, it is similar to what I am looking for. Apartment image viewing shows a loading screen while the images are loading in that viewpage.

Also for the record, can I just treat viewpagers like onCreate functions of an activity? That would really clear things up

Insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the supplied FragmentPagerAdapter if you want to perform more Activity-like lifecycle management of each page.

Comment: can you elaborate on what features I am looking for? The compatibility pack data types have very cryptic methods and little practical explanations

Comment: I am looking at it, but I dont see the intrinsic differences between ViewPager and FragmentPager

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter is a PagerAdapter implementation for use with ViewPager. It provides a layer for managing fragments as pages rather than standalone views. This would help provide you with the lifecycle management you seem to be looking for. Your derived adapter would need to generate the fragment for each page, but from there the fragments themselves could manage loading.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Where can I find a complete documentation of ViewPager? All I can find are some demos with the cryptic methods